# What h.c. stands for?

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I came across the following equation
$$ A = UAV + h.c. $$
For example, please see Eqn (2) in [here](http://www.rmki.kfki.hu/~diosi/prints/2006pra73_064101.pdf).

But I have no idea what h.c. stands for... It seems that it comes from some physics.

Any comments or answers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Hermitian conjugate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In physics, the abbreviation "h.c." usually stands for "Hermitian conjugate." So, $UAV + h.c. = UAV + (UAV)^\dagger$, where $M^\dagger$ denotes the Hermitian conjugate of the operator $M$.